# Return RegEx match in bash

Tags: regex, bash

Using bash, I can check to see if the value of a variable matches a regular expression. However, I cannot find a way of returning the part that matched.  Is this possible?

For example take `$test` as `test="123456-name-goes-here.1.2.3-something.zip"`  The part I'd like to return is `1.2.3-something`.

With the code below, I can successfully match `$test`, but I don't know where to go from here.

```
[[ $test =~ ([0-9]\.[0-9](\.[0-9])?(\.[0-9])?)(-[a-z-]*)? ]] && echo "matched"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$BASH_REMATCH[0]` will contain the value you need:

```
test="123456-name-goes-here.1.2.3-something.zip"
reg="[0-9]\.[0-9](\.[0-9])?(\.[0-9])?(-[a-z-]*)?"
if [[ $test =~ $reg ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]};
fi
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/ZYmnTY)

See [this cheatsheet](http://bl.ocks.org/magnetikonline/5282716):

> Regular expression captures will be available in `$BASH_REMATCH`, `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`, `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`, etc.

That means that the whole match value is stored in `${BASH_REMATCH}` with Index = 0, and the subsequent items cotnain submatches that were captured with `(...)` (capturing groups).